# Either json or Soap to exchange data in my project?

Tags: php, python, json, zend-framework, serialization

I am doing a car rental software, in which a front end back end are there, where the back end will do the accounting part. I have to send some data like customer name, amount, currency etc. to account engine to prepare the ledgers. I am confused whether to use json or soap for information exchange between front and back ends. ur suggestions are precious. thank u..

Comment: If you can get away with it json is almost always the go.

Comment: SOAP is much more verbose than JSON => more data to transfer and harder to read. If it works with JSON - it's most likely you don't need SOAP.

Comment: Expanding on RockyFord's comment:  If you ever find that you can't get away with JSON due to your data, you should redesign your data.  If you ever find that you can't get away with JSON due to your colleagues, you should educate or replace your colleagues.  The only sane reason I can think of to use SOAP is an unavoidable dependence on a third-party service that requires it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JSON for data serialization.  It's clean, simple, compact, widely supported, and understands data types.  Use SOAP only if you like pain.  It is a bloated sack of cruft built upon another bloated sack of cruft.

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON.

My argument is that JSON maps directly to and from native data types in common scripting languages.

If you use Python, then `None` <-> `null`, `True` <-> `true`, `False` <-> `false`, `int`/`float` <-> Number, `str`/`unicode` <-> String, `list` <-> Array and `dict` <-> Object. You feel right at home with JSON.

If you use PHP, there should be similar mappings.

XML is always a foreign language for any programming language except Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could use both.  For example, using XML bindings you get the (de)serialization of the data going across the wire for free.  That is, if you're going to be POSTing lots of data to your web-service, and want to avoid calling the equivalent of "request.getParameter" for each parameter and building your own objects and creating/registering different servlets for each endpoing, the bindings can save in development time.  And for the response, you can have the payload be defined as a String and return JSON text, which gives you the benefits of that compact, javascript-friendly of that notation.